# autologin to root user with .cshrc

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

How do we cause login cshell to automatically execute `sudo su -` when a user first ssh into the linux box from Windows putty ?

We tried putting this line `sudo su -` in .cshrc file but it is never executed. 
We also tried `echo -s "text" | sudo su -` in .cshrc file but it is never executed, even after `source .cshrc`.

Thank you 
Sincerely

Comment: Why don't you have the remote user log in as root?

Comment: The first thing you have to ask yourself why you actually NEED that feature.  The 2nd thing you have to check is whether or not the user on the box you ssh into is actually using csh (bleagh) as their login shell.

Comment: Hi terdon, think - thx for responding. its a putty.exe from windows to the regular shell and then "sudo su -" as root. the regular user default shell is a csh but root is bash